# Javascript FancyTree: is it possible to distinguish between the selection of a node and the action of expanding it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancytree

I would like to achieve the following behavior with my tree.

When someone select the corner icon that signal that the node is expandable, i would like the node to expand and only expand (no selection). Meanwhile, when someone select the node (i.e. one click the text of the node), i want that a specific handler that i made be executed and no expansion of the node.

This is because in my application, when a user select/one click an element of the tree, the element is added, to another list within the html. Let say a list of selected item.

So in other words:

- When someone oneclick the text of a node, the node should not expand
     at all, and only my handler should be executed.
- In the mean time, if someone one click, the icon on the left corner
        of a node (which actually signal that the node is expandable), i
        would like it to expand only and nothing else.

> In short, is it possible to distinguish between the selection of a
>   node and the action of expanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `clickFolderMode` to `1` will get you the behavior you're after:

> When someone select the corner icon that signal that the node is
>   expandable, i would like the node to expand and only expand (no
>   selection). Meanwhile, when someone select the node (i.e. one click
>   the text of the node), i want that a specific handler that i made be
>   executed and no expansion of the node.

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    clickFolderMode: 1 // 1:activate, 2:expand, 3:activate and expand
});
```

You should then be able to use the `onSelect` and `onExpand` event handlers to do what you need to depending on which action the user performed.